# HttpServletResponse response: Ask user to download file instead of auto downloading

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6

This is my download code.  It just starts downloading the file without asking user.  I've searched multiple forums and nothing seems to work.  This is code is in a backing bean attached to a commandButton.

```
public void doDownloadFile() {   

    PrintWriter out = null;

    try {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();   
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.csv");
        out = response.getWriter();
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(out);

        List<String[]> stringList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        for (User user : userList) {

            String[] string = {user.getEmail(), user.getName(), user.getPassword()};
            stringList.add(string);
        }

        writer.writeAll(stringList);
        out.flush();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ViewLines.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);     
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to the fact your browser is configured to download files of these types without prompt.  The code has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thank you so much!  You are correct.  Tried it on another site and same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of what to do with a download is 100% local, meaning it's the browser, not you, that determines what to do in that case.  Whether the user's browser just dumps the file in a download folder or allows him to save it to a particular spot is entirely up to the browser.

Not much to be done.